# Can the TDD methodology be applied top-down?

Tags: tdd

I'm unclear how TDD, the methodology, handles the following case. Suppose I want to implement the mergesort algorithm, in Python. I begin by writing

```
assert mergesort([]) === []
```

and the test fails with

> NameError: name 'mergesort' is not defined

I then add

```
def mergesort(a):
    return []
```

and my test passes. Next I add

```
assert mergesort[5] == 5
```

and my test fails with

> AssertionError

which I make pass with

```
def mergesort(a):
    if not a:
        return []
    else:
        return a
```

Next, I add

```
assert mergesort([10, 30, 20]) == [10, 20, 30]
```

and I now have to try to make this pass. I "know" the mergesort algorithm so I write:

```
def mergesort(a):
    if not a:
        return []
    else:
        left, right = a[:len(a)//2], a[len(a)//2:]
        return merge(mergesort(left)), mergesort(right))
```

And this fails with

> NameError: name 'merge' is not defined

Now here's the question. How can I run off and start implementing `merge` using TDD? It seems like I can't because I have this "hanging" unfulfilled, failing test for `mergesort`, *which won't pass until `merge` is finished!* If this test hangs around, I can never really do TDD because I won't be "green" during my TDD iterations constructing `merge`.

It seems like I am stuck with the following three ugly scenarios, and would like to know (1) which one of these does the TDD community prefer, or (2) is there another approach I am missing? I've watched several Uncle Bob TDD walkthroughs and don't recall seeing a case like this before!

Here are the 3 cases:

1. Implement merge in a different directory with a different test suite.
2. Don't worry about being green when developing the helper function, just manually keep track of which tests you *really* want to pass.
3. Comment out (GASP!) or delete the lines in `mergesort` that call `merge`; then after getting `merge` to work, put them back in.

These all look silly to me (or am I looking at this wrong?). Does anyone know the preferred approach?

Comment: `mergesort` isn't a use case; it is an *implementation of a use case (the actual use case being **sorting**),* and a very well-defined one at that.  You should be able to take the definition of `mergesort` and produce a very well-defined and specific set of unit tests from which you can derive your actual implementation.

Comment: So you suggest that either (1) writing `merge`, the entire complex 6-10 line function, is just a part of making the last `mergesort` test pass? Or if I wanted to use TDD on it, I do it off to the side? Did I get that right? Is it a pitch for option 1? Also, I can easily write a test set, but I'm trying to follow the three rules. This is part of an experiment to see how granular TDD can be in certain cases.

Comment: Part of the goal of TDD is to help you create a software design.  Part of that design process is discovering what is needed to produce the desired result.  In the case of `mergesort`, since it's already a very well-defined algorithm, this discovery process is not required, and it then becomes a matter of mapping what you already know to be the design to a series of unit tests.  Presumably, your top level test asserts that your method under test accepts an unsorted collection and returns a sorted one...

Comment: ...Subsequent unit tests would gradually dig deeper into the actual mechanics of a `mergesort`.  If you're looking for the "right" way to do this, there isn't one, other than to be accurate about your mapping of the `mergesort` algorithm to a series of unit tests; i.e. they should reflect what a `mergesort` actually does.

Comment: Design doesn't grow itself from unit tests alone; if you're expecting a `mergesort` design to emerge naturally from red-green-refactor, that won't happen unless you guide the process based on your existing knowledge of `mergesort`.

Comment: Makes sense, got it

Comment: In this case, like @RobertHarvey said, `mergesort` is known so you shouldn't pretend you are not aware of it. But do know TDD is not particularly well-suited to algorithm discovery. If you were trying to actually derive a new algorithm, TDD is not the best way to go about it.

Comment: Correct. I am not looking to discover. I wanted to see if doing TDD following the three rules would give me 100% test coverage and wanted to stay disciplined in not writing any code that wasn't to make a failing test pass, etc. I ran into a bit of a conundrum when trying to write this thing top-down, because jumping out to implement a sub-function while a failing unit test was hanging didn't fit the methodology. I am trying to understand whether this is a "weakness" or whether there are better approaches.

Comment: Heavily recommended: http://geekswithblogs.net/theArchitectsNapkin/archive/2014/02/10/recursively-descending-test-driven-development-aided-by-thinking.aspx

Comment: In TDD `merge` must be invented only on "refactoring" stage. If you see that `merge` method can be introduced for passing test of `mergesort` you first make your tests pass without `merge` method. Then refactor your implementation by introducing `merge` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are some alternative ways to look at your options. But first, the rules of TDD, from [Uncle Bob](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.TheThreeRulesOfTdd) with emphasis by me:

1. You are not allowed to write any production code unless it is to make a failing unit test pass.
2. You are not allowed to write any more of a unit test than is sufficient to fail; and compilation failures are failures.
3. You are not allowed to write *any more production code than is sufficient* to pass the one failing unit test.

So, one way to read rule number 3 is that you need the `merge` function to pass the test, so you can implement it -- but only in its most basic form.

Or, alternately, you start by writing the merge operation inline, and then refactor it out into a function after getting the test to work.

Another interpretation is that you're writing mergesort, you know that you'll need a `merge` operation (ie, it isn't YAGNI, which is what the "sufficient" rule attempts to curtail). Therefore, you should have started with tests for the merge, and only then proceeded to tests for the overall sort.

Comment: These are really good observations. I had thought of the inline-and-factoring out earlier, but as `merge` is surprisingly messy, edge-case-wise (as well as  useful as a standalone) the idea of doing it as a separate function made more sense. However, the style of doing it inline in its basic form and then factoring it out at the blue-hat stage really seems to be right and very much what I was looking for.

Comment: @RayToal - I actually lean toward the approach of fully testing the `merge` operation before doing the sort (as well as separate testing of the `partition` operation). I think that the claimed benefits emergent design comes from slowly working toward a known goal. In the case of mergesort, I *don't* think the goal is sorting in general (because then you'll end up with bubble sort). You know the basic operations, so you work toward those operations; the sort is mostly an afterthought.

Comment: There's a forth option. Pass the `merge` function into `mergesort` and mock its behavior. *Then* go back and implement `merge` test first. Delegates are awesome™.

Comment: @RubberDuck Mocking a integral part of the core domain could lead to some troubles, more specifically when you run the program and the mocked and merge function differ in the least detail. An approach like that should be left for instances where you're working with external resources like from where the list to sort comes from.